# Count Elements Selected Within a Slicer

Tags: excel, vba, count, slicers

I have started to work on an excel sheet and to run some calculated field I need a public function that returns the number of items selected within a single slicer. 
I surfed the internet, but unfortunately I was only able to find VBA codes that actually do not work at all. 
I have started to work with VBA only recently for the first time, so I have no experience with it.

I managed to use this code, which however is not a public function, so it cannot be used within calculated fields in pivot tables:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableChangeSync(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
        Const sSlicerName As String = "Producer"
        On Error Resume Next
        If Not IsError(Target.Slicers(sSlicerName).Name) Then _
            Range("A1") = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_" & sSlicerName) _
             .VisibleSlicerItems.Count
    End Sub
```

Did any of you face this issue and find a way to solve the problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you post one of the code you tried, even if it doesn't work? At least, to better understand which is your goal... Can you post, at least, images (editable if possible) with bifore and after the way you try processing that sheet? If not, can you better describe what "returns the number of items selected within a single slicer" means? Does your selection contain only cells of one row?

Comment: You can find a code I have tried to implement in the question above. What I am looking for is a function that returns the elements that are part of a slicer used as a filter in a Pivot Table. Within the slicer, there are several "Producers", and I would like to know the number of the selected ones, in order to use this number to calculate averages in calculated fields. I hope this clarifies the question, if not please let me know

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
Public Function CountProducers()
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Const sSlicerName As String = "Producer"

    Application.Volatile

    On Error Resume Next
        If Not IsError(Sheet1.PivotTables("PivotTable1").Slicers(sSlicerName).Name) Then
            lngCount = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_" & sSlicerName) _
             .VisibleSlicerItems.Count
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    CountProducers = lngCount
End Function
```

As you can see your initial attempt was almost correct. A few things to note:

- I added `Application.Volatile` part to make the formula dynamic, i.e. it will always re-calculate whenever you change your slicer selections.
- `On Error` ... and `If Not IsError`... parts are not really required, you can simply leave `lngCount` part all by itself. If the formula won't find a slicer called "Producer" it will simply return `#VALUE!` error.

Comment: I noticed if I clear the filter in the slicer it returned the wrong count. If you `For Each Value In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_" & sSlicerName).VisibleSlicerItems` and count up in the loop then you will get the correct value each time.